# How to force a conversion to take precedence over other conversions?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-precedence

I have classes:

```
class IntegerVector:
{
    IntegerVector operator * (const int scalar) const;
};

class RealVector:
{
    RealVector(const IntegerVector &other);
    RealVector operator * (const double scalar) const;
};
```

How can I force the expression: `integer_vector*1.5` to be equivalent to `RealVector(integer_vector)*1.5` rather than `integer_vector*int(1.5)` as it is now?

### EDIT

BTW, there are lots of these operators, so defining `RealVector IntegerVector::operator * (const double scalar) const` is not very satisfactory.

Comment: Hm. Mb use RealVector(integer_vector) * 1.5?

Comment: Haha, of course, but no, I meant implicit conversion. :-)

Comment: Implicit conversion will be available only if there is operator RealVector() in IntegerVector...

Comment: How about changing to IntegerVector operator * (RealVector real); where the implementation can control the real to scalar conversion

Comment: @ForEveR, Thanks I did not know that. Is not RealVector(const IntegerVector &) sufficient?

Comment: @Chethan, I am not sure I understand, I want product of vector*scalar, not vector*vector. vector*vector would also be defined (inner product) so I would have a problem there.

Comment: i`m wrong. no explicit constructor is sufficient.

Comment: @ForEveR: I think this was intended for me, not Chethan. :-)
Thanks. I did not even know that you can declare RealVector() in IntegerVector. I mean as a conversion operator.

Comment: I guess you could define some kind of "conversion precedence" with template meta-programming. I.e. which combination of types leads to which type and then use a free-standing template operator that employs that to do the right thing.... something like decltype(T1()*T2())

Comment: When you say you have lots of operators, are you talking about methods? Comparison? Assignment?

Comment: Method operators: *, /, +, -, etc. As well as regular methods, such as component_product. BTW, it occurs to me that integer_vector.component_product(real_vector), will plainly not work, because the compiler will not convert integer_vector (this) to a RealVector without explicit instruction. After some testing, the same holds for operator * defined as a method. So I would have to rewrite all operators as global functions. But the question is still valid: how to force the desired conversion?

Comment: You know, there's a reason people usually try to avoid implicit conversions

Comment: @jalf, Yes but in this case I can't avoid the compiler converting my doubles to ints... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11, you could leverage the built-in type promotion like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

class IntegerVector;
class RealVector;

template <class T> struct VectorForType {};
template <> struct VectorForType<int> {typedef IntegerVector type;};
template <> struct VectorForType<double> {typedef RealVector type;};

// This is where we figure out what C++ would do..
template <class X, class Y> struct VectorForTypes
{
  typedef typename VectorForType<decltype(X()*Y())>::type type;
};


class IntegerVector
{
public:
    template <class T> struct ResultVector
    {
      typedef typename VectorForTypes<int, T>::type type;
    };

    template <class T>
    typename ResultVector<T>::type operator*(const T scalar) const;
};

class RealVector
{
public:
    template <class T> struct ResultVector
    {
      typedef typename VectorForTypes<double, T>::type type;
    };

    RealVector();
    RealVector(const IntegerVector &other);

    template <class T>
    typename ResultVector<T>::type operator*(const T scalar) const;
};


int main()
{
  IntegerVector v;
  auto Result=v*1.5;
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(Result), RealVector>::value, "Oh no!");
}
```

If you need this without decltype, you can probably implement the type promotion result as a meta-function too. I suppose an operator implementation would look something like this:

```
template <class T> inline
typename ResultVector<T>::type IntegerVector::operator*(const T scalar) const
{
  typename ResultVector<T>::type Result(this->GetLength());
  for (std::size_t i=0; i<this->GetLength(); ++i)
    Result[i]=(*this)*scalar;
  return Result;
}
```

Comment: Very good! I'd like not to switch to C++11, so I am going to find a way to determine the result type of X()*Y() without decltype.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this... This is solution, but very strange, but i cannot invent something better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class IntegerVector;

class RealVector
{
public:
    RealVector(const IntegerVector &other) { }
    RealVector operator * (const double scalar) const { std::cout << "RealV called" << std::endl;  return *this; }
};

class IntegerVector
{
public:
    IntegerVector operator * (const int scalar) const
    {
       std::cout << "IntV called" << std::endl;
       return *this;
    }
    template<typename T>
    typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, int>::value, IntegerVector, RealVector>::type
    operator * (const T scalar) const
    {
       decltype(operator *<T>(scalar)) object(*this);  
       return object * scalar;
    }
};

int main()
{
   IntegerVector v;
   v * 1.5;
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/b72cde05ca287042300f4aff0f185a42